# Connect to Remote Bitcoin Node

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, full-node

Is there a free Bitcoin full node I can connect remotely? Based on my understanding, SPV nodes have to rely on full nodes, but I don't know how to connect to full nodes with SPV nodes. How can I find a public free node and how can I connect to it?

Comment: Here's a list of public bitcoin nodes https://bitnodes.io/ I'm not sure about connecting with SPV client though.

Comment: I am curious how wallet services actually connect to full node. For example, Electrum wallet is not running full node, but how is it actually connected to full node for getting transaction data?

Comment: A full node is basically a server, a server has an IP address and listens on a specific port. Electrum has a tab where you can enter the IP of the node you wish to connect to: https://armantheparman.com/connect-electrum-desktop-wallet-to-your-bitcoin-node/. There is also something called SPV or Simple Payment Verification, I don't know if they use it but theoretically it is like running a node but with the lite characteristic of a small wallet app. It is relatively important to know how to manage which nodes you are connected to.